# Expectation of function of dependent random variables

Tags: probability, expected-value, independence

Consider a real valued function $h$ on random variables, and the following sample-average function $h_S(X_1, X_2, ..., X_n) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n h(X_i).$ Assume $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$ are **not** independently distributed i.e. are dependent.

In the most general setting for $h,$ is it correct to claim that the second equality below holds? $-$ $$E_{X_1, X_2,..., X_n}[h_S(X_1, X_2, ..., X_n)] = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n E_{X_1, X_2, ..., X_n}[h(X_i)] = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n E_{X_i}[h(X_i)]$$

My approach is as follows ($f$ is the joint pdf of $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$) $-$

$$\begin{align*}E_{X_1, X_2, ..., X_n}[h(X_1)] &= \int_{X_1, X_2, ..., X_n} h(X_1) \,\, f(X_1, X_2, ..., X_n) \,\, dX_1 dX_2 ... dX_n \\ &= \int_{X_1} h(X_1) \left(\int_{X_2, ..., X_n} f(X_1, X_2, ..., X_n) \,\,  dX_2 dX_3 ... dX_n \right) dX_1\\&= \int_{X_1}h(X_1) f(X_1) \,\, dX_1 = E_{X_1}h(X_1). \end{align*}$$

My questions:

1. Is the above reasoning correct? (I am unsure of the integral splitting -- is it always possible?)
2. Is there a cleaner (more elegant) way to see this?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it is always true. It is called the linearity of expectation.

Comment: @sudeep5221 wouldn't that be relevant for the first equality (interchanging sum and expectation) -- I'm concerned about the second equality (i.e. 'ignoring' random variables other than X_i even though X_i might depend on them). Please correct me if I'm missing something!

Comment: sudeep is right. A few remarks: 1) get rid of the subscripts in your expectations, they are meaningless, and unnecessary. Your choice of notation suggests that perhaps you need to review the definition of expectation. See, for example, https://services.math.duke.edu/~rtd/PTE/PTE5_011119.pdf 2) if the $X_i$ are dependent, then there is no a priori reason to believe that $X_1,\dots,X_n$ has a density (w.r.t Lebesgue measure)

Comment: @Andrew Just to confirm, in 1), do the subscripts not make sense because h(X_1) is only a function of X_1 -- so the other X_i do not matter? (this sounds silly, but just for the sake of clarity). 

2) Curious if this fact is dealt with in the reference you suggested?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The setup is that $(\Omega,\mathcal F,P)$ is a probability space and $X_i:\Omega\to \mathbb R$ are random variables if they are measurable. In particular, if $g$ is measurable, then $g(X_1,\dots,X_n)$ is a random variable. One can define the expectation of a random variable by $$E[X] = \int_\Omega X \,dP (= \int_\Omega X(\omega)P(d\omega))$$ If the $X_i$ are defined with respect to different probability measures $P_i$, then the expression $E[g(X_1,\dots,X_n)]$ becomes meaningless. This then of course begs the question of what is $E_{X_1,\dots,X_n}[g(X_1,\dots,X_n)]$ supposed to mean.

Comment: It is (in my opinion), unfortunate that people in ML use the notation $E_X[g(X,Y)]$ to mean $E[g(X,Y)\mid Y]$ where the law of $(X,Y)$ is a product measure. In fact, there are many in ML who do not even know this is what they are actually writing down! Note your notation does not agree with this convention. As for your second question, I do not know if this is explicitly dealt with in the book. But the point is that a random vector $X$ has a density if and only if the law of $X$ is absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure (see Radon-Nikodym theorem).

Comment: Indeed, if for example $X_2 = g(X_1)$, then $(X_1,X_2)$ cannot have a density. If it did (call it $f$), then $$P(X_1,X_2 \in B) = \int_B f(x_1,x_2)dx_1dx_2$$ But $(X_1,X_2) \in $ the graph of $g$ with probability $1$. On the other hand, the lebesuge measure of the graph of a measurable function is $0$.

Comment: I would loose the practice of subscripting expectations because it really does not help and often makes things more confusing. As has already been said, in general we have $$E\left[\frac{1}{n}(h(X_1)+...+h(X_n))\right]=\frac{1}{n}(E[h(X_1)]+...+E[h(X_n)])$$ assuming $E[h(X_i)]$ are finite for all $i$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, the subscripts in the expectations don't make much sense and can be ommited. Even simpler: you have the random variables $Y_i=h(X_i)$.

And for any set of random variables (independent or not) is true that $
 E[a (Y_1+Y_2)] = a (E[Y_1] + E[Y_2])$ (expectation is a linear operator).

Then, indeed

$$E\left[ \frac{1}{n} \sum_i Y_i\right] = \frac{1}{n} \sum_i E[Y_i]$$

The only condition you need is that $Y_i=h(X_i)$ have finite mean.